# How to Triggering a Project Analysis with the SonarQube Runner?

Tags: sonarqube, sonar-runner

I am trying to setup Jenkins plugin with SonarQube.

The instructions at http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Triggering+SonarQube+on+Jenkins+Job#TriggeringSonarQubeonJenkinsJob-TriggeringaProjectAnalysiswiththeSonarQubeRunner

seems to be exactly same for both

1. Triggering a Project Analysis with the SonarQube Runner
2. Triggering a Task with the SonarQube Runner.

I am trying to trigger a project, but i am only getting the option for Task in jenkins. What am i missing?

Answer (score 1):

To analyze a project, either you set the "Project properties" or the "Path to project properties" field. See also http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Runner.

Comment: I am trying to integrate with Jenkins. How do i call it from Jenkins?

Comment: "Page Deleted - A page with this title has been deleted. Contact your space administrator if you would like it restored."

Comment: The page moved to http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Scanner